# Which airfield is "Windy?"

Tags: flight-control-hd

One of the Holiday Gift Grab achievements today is Snowball - Land 5 helicopters in a row on the Windy airfield.  The airfields don't seem to have names that I can find, though.

Are there names for the airfields anywhere?  Which one is the "Windy" airfield?

Comment: It's hard, as a first time player.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the airfield with the orange and white wind cone thing in the middle. 3rd map from the right. Good luck with the achievement!

I just unlocked it. It's definitely that one on the PC.

Comment: Ugh, I think you have to land something like 500 planes to unlock this airfield.  I played it for a bit a long time ago and I still think I'm a couple hundred away.  No thanks, Steam.  You can keep your coupon.

Comment: @agent86, at least you don't have to get 500 airplanes as a cumulative hi-score, you just need to land 500 planes across every time you play a level.

Answer (score 7):

It is the third airfield from the right, near the end of the list.  In the center of the map you'll see a orange and white windsock surrounded by airstrips.   (The direction of the wind affects which airstrips are active and changes during play).

Strategy for this achievement:

I finished this first try with only 15 planes landed total...  maybe I just got lucky?  But every 3rd or 4th was a helicopter.

Every Helicopter that entered the screen I had doing little circles near the heli landing pads, I landed all other planes that entered the screen until I had 5 helicopters all doing circles near the pads.

Then I shifted to circling all planes that entered, and quickly landed the 5 helicopters in a row.

Comment: Hi, Andrew, welcome to the site. While this may be helpful, it doesn't really answer agent86's question of which airfield you need to play on.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's the third from the right!
This was a mighty difficult achivement to get. Make sure you keep the helicopters in the air rather than the airplanes since there are about 10 airplanes for every helicopter.